# How does `tokio::pin` change the type of variable?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

```
use std::pin::Pin;

fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}

fn test(s: String) {}
fn test2(s: Pin<&mut String>) {}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("abc");
    print_type_of(&s);
    tokio::pin!(s);
    print_type_of(&s);
    // test(s); error!
    test2(s);
}
```

The question is not about why what `Pin` is or why `Pin` is needed.

The type of `s` changes from `alloc::string::String` to `core::pin::Pin<&mut alloc::string::String>` after calling `tokio::pin!`. How can this happen? Changing the type of the outside variable inside a macro surprises me.

Comment: Because it shadows the identifier inside the macro ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden But that would only happens in the inside block of the macro? `s` is outside.

Comment: There is no block inside the macro.

Comment: Macros are [different than the functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html#the-difference-between-macros-and-functions). Macro calls will be evaluated in compile time to generate code.   Please check this [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b6a0353d9969233210091dfa549938c).  it will be expanded as the comment in the main block. You can see the result by running Show HIR option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are more powerful than functions. They are evaluated at compile time, and turn into code *in the same scope* they are invoked. Despite that, a macro [can't access variables in that scope with hardcoded names, but it can if the identifier is received as a parameter.](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/minutiae/hygiene.html)

Also note that Rust allows shadowing (redeclaring) variables with the same name.

So, for example:

```
let x = 42;

print_type_of(x); //i32

let x = "foo";

print_type_of(x); //&str
```

works just fine. The two `x`'es aren't really the same variable, they just have the same identifier ("name"), and the latter makes the former inaccessible.

And a macro *can* emit the line that shadows the variable. So:

```
macro_rules! print_and_replace {
    ($var: ident) => {
        println!("{}", $var);
        let $var = "foo";
    };
}

fn main(){
    let x = 42;

    print_and_replace!(x);

    println!("{x}");
}
```

is the same* as if you wrote

```
fn main(){
    let x = 42;

    println!("{}", x);
    let x = "foo";

    println!("{x}");
}
```

<sup>*: if the identifier is passed in via an argument. It would not work if the macro [tried to access `x` directly.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3a1f4ffca77607e8028fe3dbf86b001a)</sup>

---

As for why `tokio::pin` needs to do this, stack pinning requires that the original value is never moved again. It can ensure this by shadowing the variable, making it no longer accessible.

So `pin` is not much more than this:

```
macro_rules! pin {
    ($var: ident) => {
        let $var = unsafe{ Pin::new_unchecked(&mut $var) };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I tried `macro_rules! abc {
    () => {
        let s: usize = 1;
    };
}
` with `fn main() {
    let s = String::from("abc");
    print_type_of(&s);
    tokio::pin!(s);
    print_type_of(&s);
    // test(s); error!
    test2(s);

    abc!();
    print_type_of(&s);
}
` before posting the question, but it does not compiles.

Comment: I just realized that my understanding of macros is a little off. Please wait, I'll try to figure it out and update my answer soon.

Comment: @SaddlePoint what you are trying to do is prevented via [hygiene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro)

Comment: @ÖmerErden Thanks. Didn't know about this concept. I will try to understand how `tokio::pin!`/`print_and_replace!` is different from this `abc!` macro. I've thought all of them shadow variables in the same way...

Comment: @SaddlePoint I found it out. It only works when the macro receives the identifier as an argument (i.e. it is from the same scope as the bindig the identifier identifies), but not if it is hardcoded into the macro. See [this](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/minutiae/hygiene.html) for a more detailed description.